# JavaMail Api: Read mail that has attachment

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am able to read the mail that has only the message body in it.
However if,

1) append an attachment  or/and
2) send reply to the mail

I am not able to read the message body.

```
if (StringUtils.contains(msg.getContentType(), "text/html") || StringUtils.contains(msg.getContentType(), "text/plain")){
            textMsg = msg.getContent().toString();

        } else if (StringUtils.contains(msg.getContentType(), "multipart")){
            Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            int partCount = multiPart.getCount();
            textMsg=  multiPart.getBodyPart(0).getContent().toString();     

            for (int j = 0; j < partCount; j++){
                BodyPart part = multiPart.getBodyPart(j);
                String disposition = part.getDisposition();
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                if (disposition == null){
                    // Check if plain
                    MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) part;
                    if(mbp.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){
                        MimeMultipart mmp = (MimeMultipart) mbp.getContent();                       
                    }
                    else{
                        textMsg=  multiPart.getBodyPart(0).getContent().toString();                     
                        inputStream=part.getInputStream();  
                    }

                }else{
                    textMsg = part.getContent() != null ? part.getContent().toString() : "";                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank You !!

Comment: Try the code in this [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody).  If it still doesn't work, provide more details about how it doesn't work, including the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: Thank You Bill.  that worked for me, was able to get  message from the mail body.